# Как отправить php форму при подтверждении confirm?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Видел реализации с указанием confirm в событии onclick кнопки, но мне нужно сделать это через методы jquery тк confirm должен сработать по выполнению определенного условия. Можно ли как-то реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, можно. Стоит почитать официальную документацию по [jquery submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/).

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
 var a = 0;
 $('form').on('submit',function(e){
      if (!a) {
       var confirmed = confirm('Отправить?');
        if (!confirmed) e.preventDefault(); //Отменяем submit
      }   
    a++; //Повторный submit отправит форму
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="https://www.google.ru" method="get" target="submitted">
  <input type="text" name="q">
  <button>
Submit
  </button>
</form>
```